Ubuntu VM does not work correctly with "Enable 3D Acceleration" nor without
I am using ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 10 with VirtualBox 7.0.20. In the setting I can enable or disable Display -> Enable 3D Acceleration.

Enable 3D Acceleration is enabled: Ubuntu itself can be used without any problems, only things like the title of a terminal does not work, it looks like this:


or xclock -digital looks like this

or when I start gparted:


Enable 3D Acceleration is disabled: The title of the terminal or xclock -digital works as expected, however the whole screen and windows is flickering and jumping around, making work impossible.

So basically the VM does not work. Is there a way to fix this? Should I try other settings?
The "Display adapter" for windows is: Intel Iris Xe Graphics. (Seems to be the latest driver).
VM Settings:

Base memoty 13893 MB
Processors: 4
Video Memory: 128 MB
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA (no other can be selected)
Acceleration: 3D

Host system

Windows 10.0.19045 Build 19045
System: HP EliteBook 840 G8
type: x64 based
Processor: i7-1185G6, 4 cores
RAM: 32 GB


You have asked a video related question and have not included any video info. What is the make and model of the video card and the driver being used? Please edit the question and add the info.

I added the info of the display adapter. If you need more information, please provide a way how I can retrieve that information

New hardware might be better if you ran Ubuntu 24.04

I do not have new hardware. I have to use the available hardware. There must be a way to fix this issue

There is no way anyone on this site knows what this means, I have to use the available hardware You did not give any hardware info.

What are all the video settings in the VM, especially the memory allocated? Please add this info to the question.

Additional information added. You have to ask what you need, I cannot know what you need...

Your VM video settings look ok to me (I do not use the 3d acceleration). My 22.04 virtualbox VM works fine, but it's on a Debian host. This is probably something to do with your Windows host.
